# How long would the example session in the MouseGuard corebook be?

Tags: mouse-guard

I'm trying to learn MouseGuard. So far, the snags are as follow:

1. I just finished a first read through.
2. I haven't GMed or played the game.
3. It feels like there are a lot of moving parts to keep track of: fate points, persona points, skill advancement, tests (with passes
   and fails), traits, beliefs, goals, circles, conditions, etc. etc.
   This sensation might improve after I solve (1).
4. The example mission "Find the Grain Peddler", in which three guardmice must track a possible traitor, hit a snag, find he's been eaten by a snake, fight the snake, and find a map in his cart, feels very short to me. I can't imagine how that would fill two hours of roleplaying (or even one), and I certainly can't imagine how the player's turn would fill the rest of a common session.

Now, the manual says that a normal session's turn can last from 1 to 2 hours (or more), but the example feels awfully short. I'm used to having gaming sessions of 4 hours.
Obviously, I could hit the players with more than one set of the basic events (weather, mice, animals, wilderness), but I want to know how to prep if I consider a basic mission of one of each or less of these hazards.

Comment: Not an answer: but as an introductory session where everyone is *extra slow* because they're learning, don't you want to undershoot than overshoot? And is there really a problem with finishing early?

Comment: No problem with finishing early. I just want to know that will happen. I have to plan the session, and my players expect a certain time. Some travel an hour to get to my place. Sure, I can crack open Carcassonne, but...

Comment: ... or jump right into the next adventure!

Comment: True, but then I have to know that before planning. I love improv as much as the next guy, but I like to prepare the stuff I'm improvising around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My group can usually get through 2 GM's turns and 2 players turns in 3-4 hours.  The "sample scenario" is about the depth of planning/complexity you are 'allowed' to do, by the rules - you're basically only supposed to have two obstacles with twists.  If one of those obstacles (or twists) results in a conflict, things may take a bit longer, but generally, you're not going to consume a "common session" (I'm guessing you mean a '4+ hour time block') with just the first turn for each side - which is fine.  That's why the the sample mission is basically a setup.  If you find the map, it leads to all kinds of questions that subsequent turns can work with. While the game talks about ending the session after the Players' Turn, with only one offhand mention of an 'extended session' where you go right into another GM's turn, there's really no reason to stop at that point if you don't want to.  Don't say "Oh, well, we finished the 'adventure', let's play a board game" say "Well, now we know that the peddler was on his way to Barkstone with...questionable information.  We'd better find out what he was up to!"

Comment: Right. The Carcassonne quip was just as an example. Still, if I can (typically) fit two sets of turns in 4 hours, that's what I wanted to know. And it's true that the mission in the book is just a setup.

Comment: Can you quote the book re: "The expectation is actually that you should NOT stop after one turn each"? I didn't get that impression from my reading.

Comment: I don't have a copy of the book available at the moment, but my recollection is that it pretty explicitly says "If you have time, go ahead and launch into another GM's turn.";  I mean, no it doesn't say "WHATEVER YOU DO, DO NOT STOP AFTER ONE SET OF TURNS!" or anything, but the implication is clearly "Play as much as you have time for."

Comment: I stand corrected; While there's a mention in the text of an 'Extended session' where the Players' Turn is followed immediately by another GM's turn, there isn't much talk about it.  I must be conflating the rules in my head with something I read on the MG forum or something.  Sorry about that!  I'm editing my answer to match.